# Foreach php - выполнить ограниченное количество раз

Tags: php

Есть несколько циклов *foreach*. Как сделать так, чтобы каждый из них выполнялся строго 9 раз.

Алгоритм:
Выполнился 9 раз
перешел к следующему циклу
Выполнился 9 раз
перешел к следующему циклу

Comment: почему именно foreach, а не for?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$i=0;
foreach(){
// твой код здесь
$i++;
if($i==9)break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Цикл foreach предназначен для полного прохода коллекции. Лучше воспользоваться обычным циклом for.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < min(count($array), 9); $i++) {
    $item = $array[i];
    // обработка ...
}
```

Из недостатков можно обратить внимание, на требования к массиву. Он должен содержать числовые индексы, которые начинаются с нуля.

Можно попытаться обойти это ограничение, применяя функция next и reset.

```
$item = reset($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
    if ($item === FALSE) break;
    // обработка ...
    $item = next($array);
}
```

Правда, код получается чуточку длиннее.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте ещё этот вариант:

```
function foo($array, $end = 9) {
    if ($end > 0) {
        static $all;

        $all ?: $all = $end;
        $k = $all + ($end - ($end << 1));
        $i = 0;

        if (!empty($array[$k])) {
            foreach ($array[$k] as $key => $value) {
                $view[] = "$key -> $value";

                if ($i++ >= ($all - 1)) {
                    $view[] = foo($array, --$end);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return array_filter($view);
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Использование**

> Получаем одномерные массивы (списки)

```
$array_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
$array_2 = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18];
$array_3 = [19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27];
$array_4 = [28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36];
$array_5 = [37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45];
$array_6 = [46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54];
$array_7 = [55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63];
// или одномерные ассоциативные массивы
$array_8 = [
    'a'=>'a', 'b'=>'b', 'c'=>'c', 'd'=>'d', 'e'=>'e', 
    'f'=>'f', 'g'=>'g', 'h'=>'h', 'i'=>'i'
];
$array_9 = [
    'j'=>'j', 'k'=>'k', 'l'=>'l', 'm'=>'m', 'n'=>'n', 
    'o'=>'o', 'p'=>'p', 'q'=>'q', 'r'=>'r'
];
```

> Собираем двумерный массив массивов для передачи в ф-цию

```
$array = [
    $array_1,
    $array_2,
    $array_3,
    $array_4,
    $array_5,
    $array_6,
    $array_7,
    $array_8,
    $array_9
];
```

> Передаём массив массивов в ф-цию

```
$result = foo($array);

print_r($result);
```

> [Демо-пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f9a32f54d1526eebab1b8a69ab0c54f3eace25c3)

[image: результат в браузере]

Comment: @Ершова запостил ответ.